# how to copy table data from sql server 2008 to sql server 2005 db?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

does anyone know how to copy data from a sql server 2008 db to an sql server 2005 db? I tried to use the sql server export wizard to no avail:(

Comment: Are the two servers both running?  How much data is there to copy?   There is a process that you can script the database with data.  But this only works for data less that 2 GB.

Comment: yes both running, abt 500mb of data

Comment: There are zillions of possibilities.  Including, in all likelihood, a simple "select into" between linked servers.  But here's a product I've had recent success with:  http://www.simego.com/ (PS: I'm *not* 100% sure it supports MSSQL 2005, but I believe it does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a tutorial that will walk you through generating scripts for a table including data.  This is good for a once off operation.

[Walk through on Scripting table with data](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-copy-database-with-data-generate-t-sql-for-inserting-data-from-one-table-to-another-table/)

... this is very useful when you have many table that need to be scripted, but watch for the 2GB limit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1.If both the servers are in same network,create the linked server and use 
select * into tblename from servername.dbname.dob.tblname

2.Or you can use SSIS to transfer the data

3.Use export wizard of sql server

Comment: All good options.  But there are some limits with a select * into.  This will not take indexes over, and it is not guaranteed to replicate the data types exactly.